# Mixing two audio inputs together as fast as possible ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Currently trying to mix two audio streams together to perform an overlay. (Vocals over Instruments). I have two M4A files and I want to combine them together. If the vocal track is 30 seconds, it takes roughly 32 seconds to mix them together, but was hoping for significantly faster processing.

Here is the code I'm using

```
-ss 0.300 -i /data/user/0/me.rapchat.rapchat/cache/recording.m4a -i /data/user/0/me.rapchat.rapchat/cache/beats/cc3613da-849b-47a5-97b1-b9bf3f1136db.m4a -filter_complex [0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[aout] -map [aout] /data/user/0/me.rapchat.rapchat/cache/rap.m4a
```

I've read about using the preset Ultrafast but not sure how it would fit in as I've tried adding it and gotten errors about it's placement in the command. I've also read about copying the stream "as is" and not worrying about encoding/decoding which I was curious if that would speed up the whole process.

And here are my logs for a succesful mix

```
    09-23 15:08:08.412 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
    09-23 15:08:08.412 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
    09-23 15:08:08.412 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
    09-23 15:08:08.412 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
    09-23 15:08:08.412 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
    09-23 15:08:08.412 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
    09-23 15:08:08.412 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
    09-23 15:08:08.412 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
    09-23 15:08:08.412 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
    09-23 15:08:08.412 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
    09-23 15:08:08.412 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    09-23 15:08:08.442 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/me.rapchat.rapchat/cache/recording.m4a':
    09-23 15:08:08.442 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   Metadata:
    09-23 15:08:08.442 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     major_brand     : mp42
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     minor_version   : 0
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     compatible_brands: isommp42
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     creation_time   : 2016-09-23 20:08:08
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     com.android.version: 6.0.1
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   Duration: 00:00:34.74, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     Metadata:
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:       creation_time   : 2016-09-23 20:08:08
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:       handler_name    : SoundHandle
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/me.rapchat.rapchat/cache/beats/cc3613da-849b-47a5-97b1-b9bf3f1136db.m4a':
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   Metadata:
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     major_brand     : M4A 
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     minor_version   : 0
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     compatible_brands: M4A mp42isom
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     creation_time   : 2016-06-21 20:00:19
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     artist          : 
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     album           : Rapchat
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     date            : 2016
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     composer        : 
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     title           : wrist - beat
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     encoder         : 10.2.0
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     iTunSMPB        :  00000000 00000840 000003BF 00000000004A0001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   Duration: 00:01:50.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 110 kb/s
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     Stream #1:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 259 kb/s (default)
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     Metadata:
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:       creation_time   : 2016-06-21 20:00:19
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0xf6f57140] No channel layout for input 1
    09-23 15:08:08.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0xf6f57140] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
    09-23 15:08:08.472 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: Output #0, ipod, to '/data/user/0/me.rapchat.rapchat/cache/rap.m4a':
    09-23 15:08:08.472 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   Metadata:
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     major_brand     : mp42
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     minor_version   : 0
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     compatible_brands: isommp42
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     com.android.version: 6.0.1
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:     Metadata:
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:       encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 aac
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: Stream mapping:
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   Stream #0:0 (aac) -> amerge:in0
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   Stream #1:0 (aac) -> amerge:in1
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process:   pan -> Stream #0:0 (aac)
    09-23 15:08:08.482 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    09-23 15:08:09.022 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=       9kB time=00:00:00.62 bitrate= 115.8kbits/s speed=1.22x    
    09-23 15:08:09.532 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=      21kB time=00:00:01.41 bitrate= 122.7kbits/s speed=1.39x    
    09-23 15:08:10.032 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=      34kB time=00:00:02.20 bitrate= 124.6kbits/s speed=1.45x    
    09-23 15:08:10.532 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=      47kB time=00:00:03.04 bitrate= 125.6kbits/s speed= 1.5x    
    09-23 15:08:11.052 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=      59kB time=00:00:03.83 bitrate= 126.1kbits/s speed=1.51x    
    09-23 15:08:11.552 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=      71kB time=00:00:04.62 bitrate= 126.4kbits/s speed=1.51x    
    09-23 15:08:12.062 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=      84kB time=00:00:05.41 bitrate= 126.6kbits/s speed=1.52x    
    09-23 15:08:12.582 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=      97kB time=00:00:06.24 bitrate= 126.8kbits/s speed=1.53x    
    09-23 15:08:13.072 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     109kB time=00:00:07.03 bitrate= 126.9kbits/s speed=1.54x    
    09-23 15:08:13.572 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     121kB time=00:00:07.82 bitrate= 127.1kbits/s speed=1.54x    

    09-23 15:08:14.092 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     134kB time=00:00:08.61 bitrate= 127.1kbits/s speed=1.54x    
    09-23 15:08:14.602 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     146kB time=00:00:09.40 bitrate= 127.2kbits/s speed=1.54x    
    09-23 15:08:15.122 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     159kB time=00:00:10.24 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=1.55x    
    09-23 15:08:15.592 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     171kB time=00:00:10.98 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=1.55x    
    09-23 15:08:16.112 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     183kB time=00:00:11.77 bitrate= 127.4kbits/s speed=1.55x    
    09-23 15:08:16.612 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     195kB time=00:00:12.56 bitrate= 127.4kbits/s speed=1.55x    
    09-23 15:08:17.122 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     208kB time=00:00:13.39 bitrate= 127.4kbits/s speed=1.55x    
    09-23 15:08:17.692 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     217kB time=00:00:13.90 bitrate= 127.9kbits/s speed=1.52x    
    09-23 15:08:18.162 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     223kB time=00:00:14.28 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.48x    
    09-23 15:08:18.662 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     229kB time=00:00:14.65 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.44x    
    09-23 15:08:19.202 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     235kB time=00:00:15.06 bitrate= 127.7kbits/s speed=1.41x    
    09-23 15:08:19.792 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     240kB time=00:00:15.39 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.38x    
    09-23 15:08:20.192 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     244kB time=00:00:15.67 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.34x    
    09-23 15:08:20.712 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     252kB time=00:00:16.13 bitrate= 127.7kbits/s speed=1.32x    
    09-23 15:08:21.242 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     257kB time=00:00:16.46 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.29x    
    09-23 15:08:21.752 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     260kB time=00:00:16.64 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=1.25x    
    09-23 15:08:22.272 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     264kB time=00:00:16.92 bitrate= 127.7kbits/s speed=1.23x    
    09-23 15:08:22.882 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     269kB time=00:00:17.29 bitrate= 127.6kbits/s speed=1.21x    
    09-23 15:08:23.352 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     274kB time=00:00:17.62 bitrate= 127.5kbits/s speed=1.19x    
    09-23 15:08:23.952 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     282kB time=00:00:18.13 bitrate= 127.6kbits/s speed=1.18x    
    09-23 15:08:24.372 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     285kB time=00:00:18.32 bitrate= 127.6kbits/s speed=1.15x    
    09-23 15:08:24.892 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     290kB time=00:00:18.59 bitrate= 127.6kbits/s speed=1.13x    
    09-23 15:08:25.402 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     293kB time=00:00:18.85 bitrate= 127.5kbits/s speed=1.12x    
    09-23 15:08:26.032 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     300kB time=00:00:19.24 bitrate= 127.5kbits/s speed= 1.1x    
    09-23 15:08:26.462 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     304kB time=00:00:19.57 bitrate= 127.4kbits/s speed=1.09x    
    09-23 15:08:27.042 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     309kB time=00:00:19.89 bitrate= 127.4kbits/s speed=1.07x    
    09-23 15:08:27.622 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     312kB time=00:00:20.08 bitrate= 127.4kbits/s speed=1.05x    
    09-23 15:08:28.182 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     317kB time=00:00:20.36 bitrate= 127.4kbits/s speed=1.03x    
    09-23 15:08:28.702 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     322kB time=00:00:20.68 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=1.02x    
    09-23 15:08:29.262 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     326kB time=00:00:20.96 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=1.01x    
    09-23 15:08:29.762 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     332kB time=00:00:21.38 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=1.01x    
    09-23 15:08:30.282 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     339kB time=00:00:21.80 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=   1x    
    09-23 15:08:30.892 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     345kB time=00:00:22.22 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.995x    
    09-23 15:08:31.392 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     352kB time=00:00:22.63 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.989x    
    09-23 15:08:31.942 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     359kB time=00:00:23.10 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.986x    
    09-23 15:08:32.452 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     363kB time=00:00:23.38 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.977x    
    09-23 15:08:32.932 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     367kB time=00:00:23.61 bitrate= 127.4kbits/s speed=0.966x    
    09-23 15:08:33.542 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     372kB time=00:00:23.93 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.96x    
    09-23 15:08:33.942 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     378kB time=00:00:24.31 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.955x    
    09-23 15:08:34.462 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     384kB time=00:00:24.68 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.951x    
    09-23 15:08:35.022 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     389kB time=00:00:25.05 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.945x    
    09-23 15:08:35.542 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     392kB time=00:00:25.24 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.933x    
    09-23 15:08:36.082 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     399kB time=00:00:25.65 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.931x    
    09-23 15:08:36.572 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     405kB time=00:00:26.07 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.929x    
    09-23 15:08:37.082 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     410kB time=00:00:26.40 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.924x    
    09-23 15:08:37.632 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     417kB time=00:00:26.81 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.921x    
    09-23 15:08:37.862 13909-16848/me.rapchat.rapchat I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    09-23 15:08:37.862 13909-16848/me.rapchat.rapchat I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    09-23 15:08:38.172 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     422kB time=00:00:27.14 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.915x    
    09-23 15:08:38.672 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     427kB time=00:00:27.51 bitrate= 127.3kbits/s speed=0.912x    
    09-23 15:08:39.182 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     432kB time=00:00:27.79 bitrate= 127.4kbits/s speed=0.906x    
    09-23 15:08:39.692 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     440kB time=00:00:28.25 bitrate= 127.5kbits/s speed=0.906x    
    09-23 15:08:40.202 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     449kB time=00:00:28.81 bitrate= 127.6kbits/s speed=0.909x    
    09-23 15:08:40.702 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     456kB time=00:00:29.28 bitrate= 127.7kbits/s speed=0.909x    
    09-23 15:08:41.222 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     463kB time=00:00:29.69 bitrate= 127.8kbits/s speed=0.908x    
    09-23 15:08:41.782 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     471kB time=00:00:30.16 bitrate= 127.9kbits/s speed=0.907x    
    09-23 15:08:42.282 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     477kB time=00:00:30.53 bitrate= 128.0kbits/s speed=0.905x    
    09-23 15:08:42.782 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     485kB time=00:00:31.04 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=0.906x    
    09-23 15:08:43.292 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     494kB time=00:00:31.55 bitrate= 128.2kbits/s speed=0.907x    
    09-23 15:08:43.872 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     501kB time=00:00:31.97 bitrate= 128.4kbits/s speed=0.905x    
    09-23 15:08:44.472 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     510kB time=00:00:32.48 bitrate= 128.5kbits/s speed=0.906x    
    09-23 15:08:44.872 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     516kB time=00:00:32.85 bitrate= 128.6kbits/s speed=0.904x    
    09-23 15:08:45.442 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     524kB time=00:00:33.36 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=0.903x    
    09-23 15:08:46.012 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     529kB time=00:00:33.69 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=0.898x    
    09-23 15:08:46.512 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     532kB time=00:00:33.87 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=0.891x    
    09-23 15:08:47.072 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     536kB time=00:00:34.11 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=0.885x    
    09-23 15:08:47.572 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     540kB time=00:00:34.38 bitrate= 128.7kbits/s speed=0.88x    
    09-23 15:08:47.722 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: size=     547kB time=00:00:34.45 bitrate= 130.2kbits/s speed=0.878x    
    09-23 15:08:47.722 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: video:0kB audio:541kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.207577%
    09-23 15:08:47.722 13909-13909/me.rapchat.rapchat E/Studio Process: [aac @ 0xf6f43400] Qavg: 12320.994
```

The problem is that there is some time delay on this and i'm not sure how to go about optimizing this. I'm pretty new to FFMPEG and the syntax has quite the learning curve when throwing in presets, and codecs. Will the preset ultrafast be what i'm looking for, and how do I add it to this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The codecs which make use of `ultrafast` are x264 and x265 video codecs. Suggest trying `-filter_complex amix[aout]`.

Comment: I was able to get it to work very fast using amix and ultrafast. Thank you for the suggestion!!